# Haskell Persistent out of sync

Tags: postgresql, yesod

I'm using Yesod and Persistent to make a blog (really original, eh?).

At some point, I changed my model, and Persistent said that what I was trying to do is unsafe, and that I would have to do it manually.  It said:

```
Database migration: manual intervention required.
The following actions are considered unsafe:

    ALTER TABLE "article" DROP COLUMN "date";
```

So I went ahead and ran that in Postgres.  In fact, I have gone ahead and dropped the table "article", and I get the error:

```
Migrating: CREATe TABLE "article" 
      ( "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
        "title" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        "author" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        "day" DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT DATE,
        "content" VARCHAR NOT NULL)

devel.hs: SqlError { sqlState = "42703"
                   , sqlExecStatus = FatalError
                   , sqlErrorMsg = "column \"date\" does not exist"
                   , sqlErrorDetail = ""
                   , sqlErrorHint = ""
                   }
```

Here is how the schema currently looks (as defined using Persistent):

```
-- Blog Article
Article
  title   Text
  author  Text
  day     Day default=DATE
  content MathJax
```

What is going on here?  What do I have to do to get Postgres and Persistent back in sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please change your create table code to :

```
    digoal=# CREATE TABLE "article" 
      ( "id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
        "title" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        "author" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        "day" DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT current_date,
        "content" VARCHAR NOT NULL);
    CREATE TABLE
```

PostgreSQL no DATA function, so you can use current_date instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question because digoal's solution wasn't exactly right, but he got the main idea right, so he deserves the karma.  But the real solution is too big for a comment.  Basically, I did have a problem in my Persistent schema.  As digoal said, Postgres does not have a 'date' function.  It does have 'current_date'.  So the new Persistent schema looks like:

```
-- Blog Article
Article
  title   Text
  author  Text
  day     Day default=CURRENT_DATE
  content MathJax
```