# Yesod: "Database migration: manual intervention required"

Tags: database, haskell, database-migration, yesod, persistent

In my Yesod web app I found my code - which had worked perfectly before - impossible to launch properly.

The error message was this:

> Database migration: manual intervention required.The following actions are >considered unsafe: DROP TABLE "config_d_b";

The database consists of this code:

```
    share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"]
    [persistLowerCase|
    ConfigDB
        numberOfParticipants Int
        setEndOfRegDate      Bool Maybe
        endOfRegistration    Day Maybe
        stopRegistration     Bool
        groupName            Text
        deriving Show
    |]
```

I'm working on fpcomplete and now, after logging out and leaving it alone for ten minutes, it works fine. 
I still don't want to run the risk of this happening again (presentation due in 4 days).

So, what is going on?
From this related question:
[Haskell Persistent out of sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004528/haskell-persistent-out-of-sync)
I got the impression that it had something to do with

```
    endOfRegistration    Day Maybe
```

but deleting all the related code yielded no different result.

Thanks in advance, Sophia

Comment: Did you change the table name ? If you don't need to preserve the data (since you seem to be playing with fpcomplete), you can use `runMigrationUnsafe` to migrate it anyway.